# ElasticSearch JavaScript SDK -

Tags: javascript, typescript, elasticsearch

I have this code:

```
 import * as es from '@elastic/elasticsearch';

 const c = new es.Client({node: 'http://ec2-xx-222-xx-107.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:9200'});

 client.search({
    index: 'foo',
    body: {
      value: true
    }
  }).then(v => {
    log.info(v.body.hits);
  });
```

and I got this error:

> ```
> ResponseError: parsing_exception
>     at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/Users/alex/codes/interos/@interos/elastic-search/node_modules/@elastic/elasticsearch/lib/Transport.js:287:25)
>     at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:208:15)
>     at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1154:12)
>     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:77:11)
> ```

It's unclear why the error occurs, does anyone know why?

Comment: Could you try executing this and paste the error
 `client.search({
 index: 'foo',
    body: {
      value: true
    }
}, (err, { body }) => {
  if (err) console.log(err)
})`

Comment: This is likely an error from "value" not being a valid attribute in Elasticsearch search JSON bodies.

Comment: So a key called "value" is not kosher? seems weird that it woudn't allow everything